# Authorize.net Webhooks - need detailed error message

Tags: debugging, salesforce, webhooks, authorize.net, authorize.net-webhooks

We are trying to get up to speed using Authorize.net Webhooks to connect to our Salesforce external site. Our Salesforce endpoint seems to be working OK, because I can call it using curl from the command line and pass a JSON structure that gets successfully saved to our database. This much works fine.

However when I enter the URL of our Webhook into the "Endpoint URL:" field in Authorize.net and click the "Test Webhook" button, I get the error message:

"Error: Error occured in connecting to the endpoint: (prints my endpoint URL)

I am sure that I am calling the correct URL because I have copied and pasted it from the command line into the Endpoint URL field. But I need to know why I'm getting this error. Is there a debug log for Webhooks? Or how can I get a more detailed error message from Authorize.net?

Just be clear - this is testing a webhook call from Authorize.net -> Salesforce.

Edit: the CURL call that works from the command line is:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"test":"this"}' \
https://my.server.com/mysite/services/apexrest/PYMT_AuthnetHook
```

Thanks and Best Regards!

Comment: Doesn't look like an Authorize.Net error but a Salesforce issue. Authorize.Net will return a detailed error message in their response if there is a problem. If you don't see one then that is further evidence this is a Salesforce problem.

Comment: Thanks John. If I am testing the webhook from Authorize.net's website, how do I get a log of the error from Authorize.net? Also, I can connect to Salesforce both from the command line and using a Chrome plugin called 'Advanced REST Client'. I'm getting back a good response in those cases.